# How to simplify data checking that iterates by rows and columns (two nested loops) with if_else

Tags: r, validation, loops

```
Q1 <- c(1, 1, 2, 2)
Q2_1 <- c(3, 3, 3, 3)
Q2_2 <- c(3, 4, 2, 1)

data <- data.frame(cbind(Q1, Q2_1, Q2_2))
```

I need to do some data checking if values in Q1 variables do not appear in Q2 variables (in both Q2_1 and Q2_2) and I need the result in a single variable.
For now I was using to nested for loops (for rows and columns) with if_else function from dplyr but it's quite a lot of code and I have to do similar checks multiple times. Is there any way to simplify the code?

For now that what I'm doing:

```
Q2_index <- grep("Q2_", names(data))

data$Q2_error <- 0 
for(i in 1:dim(data)[1]){
    for(j in 1:length(Q2_index)){
        data$Q2_error[i] <- if_else(data$Q2_error != 1 & data$Q1 == data[, Q2_index[j]], 1, 0, 0)[i]
    }
}
```

Second example:

```
ID <- 1:3
Q1_1 <- 1:3
Q1_2 <- c(3, NA, 1)
Q1_3 <- c(4, 2, 1)
Q2_1 <- c(5, 2, 1)
Q2_2 <- c(1, NA, NA)
Q2_3 <- c(NA, NA, NA)

data <- data.frame(ID, Q1_1, Q1_2, Q1_3, Q2_1, Q2_2, Q2_3)

Q1_index <- grep("Q1_", names(data))
Q2_index <- grep("Q2_", names(data))

data$Q1Q2error <- 0
for(i in 1:dim(data)[1]){
    for(j in 1:length(Q1_index)){
        data$Q1Q2error[i] <- if_else(data[, Q1_index[j]] >= 1 & data[, Q2_index[j]] != data[, Q1_index[j]] & is.na(data[, Q2_index[j]]), 0, 1, 1)[i]
  } 
}
```

Evaluated conditions vary from check to check. As a result I need a single variable that indicates if I deal with an error so I can easily match the error to ID (so either 1 and 0 or TRUE, FALSE). Please notice that this is simplyfied example and I have to deal with around 10-20 Q1 or Q2 variables at the same time.

Comment: I feel the example you provided is not representative of your whole problem. Do you have multiple columns to be checked against multiple columns?

Comment: I presented the simples exaple of what I have to do. But there are also checks where I need to check multiple columns by multiple columns. In all the cases it would be best if I could store results in a single variable that indicates if I have an error or not. Conditions to check also change from check to check. If it helps I can give a second example in a few minutes.

Comment: Ye, Please do. And also give the expected outcome

Comment: Added second example. If I still did not included any informations that could be helpful please let me know.

Comment: I think you changed the condition in the second example, hence it doesnt produce what you described

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not to create a generic function for the desired operation so you can reuse it on new data frames:

```
aggreg_it <- function(data){
cols_Q1 <- names(data)[grep("Q1", names(data))]
cols_Q2 <- names(data)[grep("Q2", names(data))]
mapply(function(i,j) {ifelse(length(intersect(i, j))>0,1,0)}, 
       strsplit(apply(data[, cols_Q1], 1, paste, collapse=","),","), 
       strsplit(apply(data[, cols_Q2] , 1, paste ,collapse=","),","))
}
data$result <- aggreg_it(data)
#  ID Q1_1 Q1_2 Q1_3 Q2_1 Q2_2 Q2_3 result
#1  1   10    3    4    5    1   NA      0
#2  2   11   NA    2    2   NA   NA      1
#3  3   12    1    1    1   NA   NA      1
#4  4   13    5    6    7    8    9      0
```

as you did not  make assumptions about NAs, note that NAs are considered as valid values in this example. Hope this brings you forward. similar you could make a funcion from your code.

Data used:

```
ID <- 1:4
Q1_1 <- c(10,11,12,13)
Q1_2 <- c(3, NA, 1, 5)
Q1_3 <- c(4, 2, 1, 6)
Q2_1 <- c(5, 2, 1, 7)
Q2_2 <- c(1, NA, NA, 8)
Q2_3 <- c(NA, NA, NA, 9)
data <- data.frame(ID, Q1_1, Q1_2, Q1_3, Q2_1, Q2_2, Q2_3)
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for a loop, these operations are vectorized in R.
(I changed your input data a bit to show differentiated results)

Base R:

```
data$Q1_in_Q2 <- data$Q1 %in% data$Q2_1 | data$Q1 %in% data$Q2_2

data 
#>   Q1 Q2_1 Q2_2 Q1_in_Q2
#> 1  1    1    5     TRUE
#> 2  3    3    4     TRUE
#> 3  2    3    2     TRUE
#> 4  6    3    1    FALSE
```

With `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

data <- data %>% 
  mutate(Q1_in_Q2_1 = Q1 %in% Q2_1,
         Q1_in_Q2_2 = Q1 %in% Q2_2,
         Q1_in_Q2 = Q1_in_Q2_1 | Q1_in_Q2_2) %>% 
  select(Q1, Q2_1, Q2_2, Q1_in_Q2_1, Q1_in_Q2_2, Q1_in_Q2)

data
#>   Q1 Q2_1 Q2_2 Q1_in_Q2_1 Q1_in_Q2_2 Q1_in_Q2
#> 1  1    1    5       TRUE       TRUE     TRUE
#> 2  3    3    4       TRUE      FALSE     TRUE
#> 3  2    3    2      FALSE       TRUE     TRUE
#> 4  6    3    1      FALSE      FALSE    FALSE
```

#### Data:

```
Q1 <- c(1, 3, 2, 6)
Q2_1 <- c(1, 3, 3, 3)
Q2_2 <- c(5, 4, 2, 1)
data <- data.frame(cbind(Q1, Q2_1, Q2_2))
```

Comment: If I have 20 or more Q2 variables it is still a lot of code and I would really want to make it shorter. Could there be any other way to do that? It still helps with the for loops so many thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Hence my comment. You need to show that so people can give generic answers. Please update your example